# Incredibly high Initial server response time

Tags: pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

Is anyone here receiving an incredibly high Initial server response time? We're seeing upwards of 1.5s, however when using network tools, the server response time is sitting at < 150ms, so unless Google is doing these speed tests from a cave somewhere in the Amazon, we can't figure it out.

With the upcoming changes to ranking based on these arbitrary scores, does anyone have any insights here?

Comment: Where is your server based, are you using a CDN etc. More importantly do you know how Google applies throttling to Lighthouse to simulate a 4G connection and a slow CPU? If not have a little read of https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/master/docs/throttling.md as it might at least start to give you an idea. Do you have a public URL that you can put in the comments as at the moment there is nothing we can do to help as there is no debugging info.

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing very inaccurate performance measurements from Page Speed insights. is disappointing there is such little detail about the timing and network requests happening. The TTFB when running via their website is like 16s but when I test from nearly anywhere else, including via a proxy on the other side of the world, through tor, etc, the real TTFB is like 190ms.

There are problems with page speed insights that Google is not handling. So I suppose my answer is ***it's a disappointing and inaccurate tool.***

All of that said, I would suggest trying the built in lighthouse tool inside chrome dev tools, this will show better scores for performance, but the outstanding question is how is google themselves measuring my websites performance?

Comment: Yeah, and the problem with using the Chrome version rather than the page speed insights version, is that I assume Google isn't using the Chrome Extension version for the upcoming page ranking algo

Comment: @LeeR is actually driving me crazy. Another one of the many issues in how google decides which sites to rank higher... They should provide more support or documentation for these systems or get rid of them, what a mess.

Comment: @LeeR my understanding is they will use average chrome experience data not PSI score so you're fine, but which also means weird things like you will be punished for having visitors with old phones / slow networks.

Comment: @JPSilvashy, that would be nice, but Google being Google that ain't ever going to happen. They're not doing what Microsoft did to the net in the early days with IE6

Comment: @pguardiario I think this is the case if your site has high enough traffic to use the Chrome Experience, however on some of the sites I'm testing, they have the notice at the top saying there's not enough data from the Chrome Experience, so I assume it's just using the tested data. Google are too secretive when they have too much control over what gets presenting on the internet

Comment: 2s initial response times according to PageSpeed insights but lighthouse says 290ms.. Totally ridiculous.

Comment: Uny updates on the issue guys? Have you solved it?

Comment: @NickKharchenko no update, i've submitted to google's mailing list and other channels and they deleted my messages and threads. It's an utter coverup how they rank sites, I think thats the real answer.